# Pointer to merged 2D array

Tags: c, pointers

This should be really simple, couple of hours already spent but I am still not able to figure this out.

I just need a pointer to merged 2D arrays.

```
int a1[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
int a2[4][3] = {{7,8,9}, {6,9,6}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};

// This is fine
int (*p)[3] = a1;

// compilation error - incompatible types int[3] from type int (*)[3]
*(p + 2) = a2
```

I understand the problem, but unable to fix this.

Comment: Oops sorry, wrong question. These arrays can't be merged. There are not in contiguous memory. I will close the question.

Comment: @ZEN.Kamath What arrays *can* be merged?

Comment: @cmaster Yes i couldn't edit my comment so deleted it

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't assign arrays in C, and that's what the statement `*(p + 2)` is trying to do: It dereferences `p` once, which results in an array of three integers (that's what `p` is pointing to), and you can't assign anything to that array.